# Canvas - lineTo (x, y) not generating more that one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm currently learning HTML5 canvas, and Javascript - I would like the line to continue randomly. I know that moveTo(x,y) will generate the start point of a line, and usually if i keep stacking lineTo(x,y) it will generate a new line segment starting from where the last lineTo(x,y) left off from. I tried to make the lineTo(x,y) choose a random coordinate using var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth; and var y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;. It's not behaving the way i assumed.

Does anybody know a way i can create more line segments that are randomly generated? [CodePen Here](https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/Rgvwvz?editors=1010)

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  var y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;

  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(300, 200);
  c.lineTo(x, y);
  c.lineTo(x, y);
  c.strokeStyle = "red";
  c.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have these two lines inside the `for` loop:

```
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(300, 200);
```

Which is starting a new path from the same starting point on each iteration, instead of continuing with the previous one.

To fix it, move that out of the `for`, just before it.

Also, I would advise you to move these other two lines after it:

```
c.strokeStyle = 'red';
c.stroke();
```

Creating a path with with multiple points/lines and drawing all of them at once is more efficient than calling `stroke` for each of them.

All together, it will look like this:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(300, 200);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  var y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;

  c.lineTo(x, y);
}

c.strokeStyle = 'red';
c.stroke();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Oh! I did not think about that. First time using a loop. I should only put what i want randomly generated through a loop inside the loop function, and leave the starting point outside of the function because i do not need the start position to be looped? 

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not due to canvas but the for loop that you are using. Your for loop will run exactly once, hence drawing just one line. If you want to draw more than one line than increase the loop and move beginpath and moveTo outside of it.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
 c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(300, 200);
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  var y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;       
  c.lineTo(x, y);     
  c.strokeStyle = "red";
  c.stroke();
  
}
```

```css
body {margin:0px;}
canvas {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I probably explained the issue wrong. I actually tried this myself, and those results were not what i was looking for. I'd like the line segments to start from one another. Almost like a random zig-zag pattern. Here is a snippet of me getting 2 line segments to attach. My goal is to generate more line segments starting from the last one, but randomly generated. https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/Rgvwvz

Comment: var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  var y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
  
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(300, 200);
  c.lineTo(x, y);
  c.lineTo(300, 300);
  c.strokeStyle = "red";
  c.stroke();
}

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in your code is drawing a single line to your randomly generated point, then another line to the exact same point, from the exact same point -- which isn't a line at all! That is why you're only seeing the one.

You should set your line's origin outside of the loop, then have a single call to `lineTo` inside the loop.

Also, a loop that iterates only once isn't much of a loop! Note how I have changed the conditions of the loop to stop at `i < 3` so it creates 3 lines total. Change this depending on how many lines you want to draw:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(300, 200);
c.strokeStyle = "red";

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  var y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
  c.lineTo(x, y);
  c.stroke();
}
```